# Make text italic using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension and I want to make a string have an italic font style.

I want the output to be this :

*Future Feature:*  Suggest a Term

I tried this:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");

var s = "Future Feature: ";
s = s.italics();
var t1 = document.createTextNode(s);

var t2 = document.createTextNode("Suggest a Term");
div.appendChild(t1);
div.appendChild(t2);
```

But thats how it was rendered :

```
<i>Future Feature: </i> Suggest a Term
```

Comment: What is the question ? Why didn't you go with `css` ?

Comment: `createTextNode` creates a textNode!

Answer (score 0):

`String.prototype.italics()` has been [removed from the Web standards](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/italics).

`.italics()` return a string containing a  HTML element so can be appended to another node, example below (please inspect HTML you will see `<i>` tag within div `text`):

```js
var s = "Future Feature: ";
s = s.italics();
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = s;
```

```html
<div id="text">Future Feature: </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('input[name="textStyle"]').change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == 'bold'){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) $('input[name="styledText"]').css('font-weight', 'bold');
        else $('input[name="styledText"]').css('font-weight', 'normal');
    }
    else if ($(this).val() == 'italic'){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) $('input[name="styledText"]').css('font-style', 'italic');
        else $('input[name="styledText"]').css('font-style', 'normal');
    }
    else if ($(this).val() == 'underline'){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) $('input[name="styledText"]').css('text-decoration', 'underline');
        else $('input[name="styledText"]').css('text-decoration', 'none');
    }
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Bold:<input name="textStyle" type="checkbox" value="bold"/>
Italic:<input name="textStyle" type="checkbox" value="italic"/>
Underline:<input name="textStyle" type="checkbox" value="underline"/>

<input name="styledText" type="text" value="">
```